# Magento2: I can't add/edit product due to the issue: The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again

Tags: magento2.3.6

I don't know how to fix this problem. Currently, I'm unable to add or edit product in the backend.

[image]

Comment: please first do index:reindex and then try to add stock think this will help you.

Comment: thank you for replay @RohitGohel not fixed i'm rendexed this and i'm try it not fix

Comment: Have you checked into the system.log or excaption.log? first, delete all logs and then try to save the product and check the log file They will be sure to define what the exact issue is going on.

Comment: @Nino it may be elastic search issue, could you please check the search status.

Comment: sorry for being late @MohitPatel sure i have install elastic search amasty module or you mean elastic search installed tool i have magento 2.3.6 hes installed by wizard page But this problem appeared when installing the add-ons. I will delete the add-ons and try that

Comment: @rohitGohel i will check this now

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the indexers mode from **save** to **schedule**. and then execute the indexers once & cache flush.

After that, the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

please check Elasticsearch service enable or disable ?

> sudo service elasticsearch status